# $\infty$-categorical understanding of Bridgeland stability?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, derived-categories, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

On triangulated categories we have a notion of [Bridgeland stability conditions](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v166-n2-p01.pdf).

Is there any known notion of "derived stability conditions" on a stable $\infty$-category $C$ such that they become Bridgeland stability conditions after passing to the homotopy category $hC$?

Comment: I do not know much about the topic but try to have look at:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04658.pdf

Comment: This looks useful @SimoneVirili!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is chapter 7 of [Fosco Loregian's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14295), linked from his webpage. The paper Simone Virili linked to is one of 3 papers making up the thesis. Specifically, Section 7.2.1 discusses the topology, after Bridgeland, and proves the comparison you asked for. The setting is a slight generalization of that of Bridgeland's original papers, as Loregian makes clear.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!